# Visual Studio Conditional Breakpoints With C++/CX Variables Fail To Evaluate

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, c++-cx

When running the following statement in vs conditional breakpoints, the statement fails to evaluate:
`data->Size != 0`

The error that occurs is:
`The breakpoint cannot be set. Type name is not allowed`.

Size is an unsigned int. Same issue with `Platform::String`.

Comment: Would you please share the code in your issue? Please also share the detailed steps about how you set the Conditional breakpoints, so we could really repro this issue in our side.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Just to make this issue clearly, if you don't use the conditional breakpoint, could you add a simple breakpoint in your code line? In addition, if a variables value changes, which is known as the data breakpoint, and it is only available for VC++. Maybe you could use it in your side. If you get any update, feel free to share it here.